# read each line of a text file using cron schedule

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, google-cloud-datastore, google-drive-api

I want to use cron schedule to read each line of a text file.

```
cron:
- description: read a line of text file
  url: /read
  schedule: every 1 minutes
```

But GAE only allow to read a text file without modifying it.

How can I make the request `read` to know that the previous line was already read and it should read the next line. I dont want to store all the read line in datastore and then do query, check if the text line is in datastore or not, bla bla, because I have million of lines.

Please advice. I am thinking about Google Drive Api, any idea about that? Thanks

UPDATE: Can I do like this

```
with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
        txt= f.readlines()
f.close()

t = txt[line_num]
DO SOMETHING
line_num = line_num+1
deferred.defer( read_deferred, line_num, _countdown = 60 ) # 60 sec = 1 min
```

and in somewhere else, I trigger deffered by calling

```
deferred.defer( read_deferred, 0, _countdown = 60 ) # 60 sec = 1 min
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cron won't let you save the state, except in database. Since you don't want to use DB, you may use deferred task instead, start it once and it will keep going until the last line is read, something like:

```
def read_deferred(last_pos) :
    f = open( ... )

    if last_pos : f.seek(last_pos)

    # here you read the next line and do whatever you like,
    # just don't go further and return once you hit EOF

    last_pos = f.tell()

    deferred.defer( read_deferred, last_pos, _countdown = 60 ) # 60 sec = 1 min
```

and you call it first time like:

```
    deferred.defer( read_deferred, _countdown = 60 ) # 60 sec = 1 min
```

Comment: lenki: how can I stop the process when I hit the EOF? If I have to open the file every time, will google increase the fee for datastore read operation? google document (https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred) says that "Task Queue items are limited to 10kb of associated data. This means that when the deferred library serializes the details of your call, it must amount to less than 10 kilobytes in order to fit on the Task Queue directly", does it mean that the input.txt file size must be smaller than 10kb?

Comment: once you hit EOF, just return from the function and don't call `defer(...)` anymore. if you put your file along with your python scripts, it won't be saved to the datastore. 10kb limit for `TaskQueue` is the maximum size of the data passed between runs -- in your case the contents of the `last_pos`, which is quite small to worry about.

Comment: can I use f.readlines() instead of using seek() and tell() as in the update of my question?

Comment: sure, you can. just check if `line_num` is within the number of lines in your file, otherwise it's very easy to run away, especially with deferred tasks, that will be called again and again in case of error.

Comment: I tried with your method and my method, deferred task stop after 10-15 times. I think google does not accept this unlimited loop. Do you think so?

Comment: i have tasks that get called many times, haven't seen any that stop without any reason.

Comment: really? or because my text.txt file is too big? it is 7mb

Comment: you may try to print the line you've just read to the log file using `logging.info( line )` and see what line becomes the last to read. maybe you check for EOF the way, that considers an empty line to be the end of file?

Comment: thanx. Please look at the log image http://dl.dropbox.com/u/27576887/log.JPG . I got this error after 7-10 lines were read successfully

Comment: obviously where's a module missing named `werkzeug` in your program, please, check your imports.

Comment: I have from werkzeug import (
  unescape, redirect, Response,
)
from werkzeug.exceptions import (
  NotFound, MethodNotAllowed, BadRequest
)
 Will it enough? I am going to add "from werkzeug import *" also

Comment: and if module werkzeug is missing, why does the referred task works for first few line reading?...

Comment: i thought because I forgot to do f.close() so I added it. But it still does not solve the problem

Comment: on the log entry, that contains error message, click "+" (expand) and read what exactly error message says, because just the beginning does not provide enough information. and yeah, reading japanese from file is usually a lot of fun, I hope you did not forget to specify the correct encoding =)

Comment: it is so strange, but I change the app version from 1 to 2 in app.yaml and update the app, run it, and it works just perfect. Thanx for help