# f.seek() and f.tell() to read each line of text file

Tags: python, file-io, seek, tell

I want to open a file and read each line using `f.seek()` and `f.tell()`:

test.txt:

```
abc
def
ghi
jkl
```

My code is:

```
f = open('test.txt', 'r')
last_pos = f.tell()  # get to know the current position in the file
last_pos = last_pos + 1
f.seek(last_pos)  # to change the current position in a file
text= f.readlines(last_pos)
print text
```

It reads the whole file.

Comment: Yes, that's what `readlines` does. What's your question exactly?

Comment: I need to read line by line, save the last_pos somewhere, close the file, go and open the file, seek the last_pos, read the line, update the last_pos, close the file...

Comment: @John, if you're passing data between subprocesses, look at StringIO etc. Or consider using a database e.g. MySQL

Answer (score 20, accepted):

ok, you may use this:

```
f = open( ... )

f.seek(last_pos)

line = f.readline()  # no 's' at the end of `readline()`

last_pos = f.tell()

f.close()
```

just remember, `last_pos` is not a line number in your file, it's a byte offset from the beginning of the file -- there's no point in incrementing/decrementing it.

Comment: lenik: I cold not understand the file reading process in your answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15527617/read-each-line-of-a-text-file-using-cron-schedule. So I open a new question here:)

Comment: ok, here's how it goes. you have a variable `last_pos`, which contains the current byte offset from the beginning of the file. you open the file, `seek()` to that offset, then read a line using `readline()`. file pointer automatically advances to the beginning of the next line. then you use `tell()` to get the new offset and save it to the `last_pos` to be used on the next iteration. please, point out which part of this process is not clear, I'll try to explain in more details.

Comment: you're welcome! =) sorry I did not explain it well the first time

Comment: @lenik the 's' in `readlines` is not a typo, it's another implemented method ([doc](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_readlines.htm))

Comment: A great blog post on this method: http://www.blopig.com/blog/2016/08/processing-large-files-using-python/

Comment: This was really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Let me add this would not work if using codecs.open  (would have saved me some time to know that!)

Comment: Thanks for mentioning file.tell().  I always appreciate direct answers as opposed to "why are you doing that? you should do it this way"   When OP's are asking a question, they have to balance giving enough detail and too much detail which would unnecessarily complicate the quesiton.   In my case, i want to call a function to grab the next "n" lines of a file for a batch process on huge files.  I knew i could use the offset, but didn't know how to get the current offset, so thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason why you have to use f.tell and f.seek? The file object in Python is iterable - meaning that you can loop over a file's lines natively without having to worry about much else:

```
with open('test.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:
        #work with line
```

Comment: no no, I have special reason i need to use f.tell and f.seek.

Comment: would you be so kind to inform us about your special reason?

Comment: @John - why do you need to close the file each time?

Comment: Another reason could be the need to preserve the current position reached, to be able to resume reading at a later time (e.g. say you are writing a log parser).

Answer (score 0):

A way for getting current position When you want to change a specific line of a file:

```
cp = 0 # current position

with open("my_file") as infile:
    while True:
        ret = next(infile)
        cp += ret.__len__()
        if ret == string_value:
            break
print(">> Current position: ", cp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Skipping lines using islice works perfectly for me and looks like is closer to what you're looking for (jumping to a specific line in the file):

```py
from itertools import islice

with open('test.txt','r') as f:
    f = islice(f, last_pos, None)
    for line in f:
        #work with line
```

Where last_pos is the line you stopped reading the last time. It will start the iteration one line after last_pos.

Comment: But how can I get last position?